# Sobolev Space dual

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I'm interested in the dual space of the Sobolev space $H^1(\Omega)$ for $\Omega$ a bounded smooth domain. Of course, because $H^1(\Omega)$ being a Hilbert space, it's dual is isomorphic to itself, but this is if we use as dual pairing the $H_1(\Omega)$ scalar product:
$$(u,v)_1 = \int_\Omega \nabla u \nabla v + \int_\Omega u v$$
but what I want is a representation that is compatible with the $L^2(\Omega)$ duality product, similarly as what happen with the space $H_0^1(\Omega)$, that is also isomorphic to it's dual, but with the $L^2(\Omega)$ product, is represented as derivatives of $L^2(\Omega)$ functions.
Moreover, because of the inclusions
$$ H_0^1(\Omega) \subseteq H^1(\Omega) \subseteq L^2(\Omega)$$
then we have
$$ L^2(\Omega) \subseteq (H^1(\Omega))^* \subseteq H^{-1}(\Omega)$$
so the representation should be the functions of the for $f + \sum \partial_i g_i$ for $f, g_i\in L^2(\Omega)$ that satisfy certain additional condition.

Comment: This is explained in Adams's book on Sobolev spaces, but to be honest, I never quite understood that explanation.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thanks for the reference, I'll look it up. Do you remember more or less in which part it was?

Comment: Yes, it starts on pag. 47

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Ok, Thank you. So basically what it says is that there in this case there is not an easy way of representing it.